# Feature names from OneHotEncoder

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am using OneHotEncoder to encode few categorical variables (eg - Sex and AgeGroup). The resulting feature names from the encoder are like - 'x0_female', 'x0_male', 'x1_0.0', 'x1_15.0' etc.

```
>>> train_X = pd.DataFrame({'Sex':['male', 'female']*3, 'AgeGroup':[0,15,30,45,60,75]})

>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> encoder = OneHotEncoder()
>>> train_X_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(train_X[['Sex', 'AgeGroup']])
```

```
>>> encoder.get_feature_names()
>>> array(['x0_female', 'x0_male', 'x1_0.0', 'x1_15.0', 'x1_30.0', 'x1_45.0',
       'x1_60.0', 'x1_75.0'], dtype=object)
```

Is there a way to tell `OneHotEncoder` to create the feature names in such a way that the column name is added at the beginning, something like - Sex_female, AgeGroup_15.0 etc, similar to what Pandas `get_dummies()` does.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

A list with the original column names can be passed to `get_feature_names`.

```py
>>> encoder.get_feature_names(['Sex', 'AgeGroup'])

array(['Sex_female', 'Sex_male', 'AgeGroup_0', 'AgeGroup_15',
       'AgeGroup_30', 'AgeGroup_45', 'AgeGroup_60', 'AgeGroup_75'],
      dtype=object)
```

- DEPRECATED: [`get_feature_names`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names) is deprecated in 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2. Please use [`get_feature_names_out`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names_out) instead.

  - As per [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

```py
>>> encoder.get_feature_names_out(['Sex', 'AgeGroup'])

array(['Sex_female', 'Sex_male', 'AgeGroup_0', 'AgeGroup_15',
       'AgeGroup_30', 'AgeGroup_45', 'AgeGroup_60', 'AgeGroup_75'],
      dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 23):

- `type(train_X_encoded)` → `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`

  - Use [`pandas.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix.html) to load a sparse matrix, otherwise convert to a dense matrix and load with `pandas.DataFrame`.

```py
# pandas.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix will load this sparse matrix
>>> print(train_X_encoded)

  (0, 1)    1.0
  (0, 2)    1.0
  (1, 0)    1.0
  (1, 3)    1.0
  (2, 1)    1.0
  (2, 4)    1.0
  (3, 0)    1.0
  (3, 5)    1.0
  (4, 1)    1.0
  (4, 6)    1.0
  (5, 0)    1.0
  (5, 7)    1.0

# pandas.DataFrame will load this dense matrix
>>> print(train_X_encoded.todense())

[[0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

```py
import pandas as pd

column_name = encoder.get_feature_names_out(['Sex', 'AgeGroup'])
one_hot_encoded_frame = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(train_X_encoded, columns=column_name)

# display(one_hot_encoded_frame)
   Sex_female  Sex_male  AgeGroup_0  AgeGroup_15  AgeGroup_30  AgeGroup_45  AgeGroup_60  AgeGroup_75
0         0.0       1.0         1.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0
1         1.0       0.0         0.0          1.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0
2         0.0       1.0         0.0          0.0          1.0          0.0          0.0          0.0
3         1.0       0.0         0.0          0.0          0.0          1.0          0.0          0.0
4         0.0       1.0         0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          1.0          0.0
5         1.0       0.0         0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          1.0
```

- From `scikit-learn v1.0` use [`get_feature_names_out`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names_out) instead of [`get_feature_names`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for a nice solution. @Nursnaaz
The sparse matrix needs to convert into a dense matrix.

```
column_name = encoder.get_feature_names(['Sex', 'AgeGroup'])
one_hot_encoded_frame =  pd.DataFrame(train_X_encoded.todense(), columns= column_name)
```

- From `scikit-learn v1.0` use [`get_feature_names_out`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names_out) instead of [`get_feature_names`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names)