# Display feature names in columns after using One Hot encoding

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray, one-hot-encoding

I have one column in a csv which are the names of fruits which I want to convert into an array.

Sample csv column:

```
Names:
Apple
Banana
Pear
Watermelom
Jackfruit
..
..
..
```

There are around 400 fruit names in the column

I have used one hot encoding for the same but unable to display the column names(each fruit name from a row of the csv column)

My code till now is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

dataset = pd.read_csv('D:/fruits.csv')
X= dataset.iloc[:, 0].values


labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
D= labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X)
D = D.reshape(-1, 1)

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(D)
```

This converts the data of the column into a numpy array but the columns names are coming as [0   1   2   3 .. ..] which I want as each row name of the csv, example [Apple     Banana    Pear    Watermelon .. .. ]

How can I retain the column names after using one hot encoding

Comment: can you add your current output & desired output in question?

Comment: `.values` changes dataframe to numpy array which doesn't support string column names. You can try `X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns   = dataset.columns)`

Comment: @SachinPrabhu I am getting the error "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 68197), indices imply (3, 68197)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Feature names from OneHotEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54570947/feature-names-from-onehotencoder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Orignal Answer:**

A rather efficient way to OneHotEncode would be to use `pd.get_dummies`.
I've applied on sample data:

```
data = {'Names':['Apple','Banana','Pear', 'Watermelon']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df_new = pd.get_dummies(df)
print(df_new)
```

Orignal df:

```
        Names
0       Apple
1      Banana
2        Pear
3  Watermelon
```

Encoded df:

```
   Names_Apple  Names_Banana  Names_Pear  Names_Watermelon
0            1             0           0                 0
1            0             1           0                 0
2            0             0           1                 0
3            0             0           0                 1
```

**Edit:**

Let's assume that our dataframe contains 2 Categorical & 2 Numeric features. We just want to OneHotEncode 1 of the 2 Categorical columns.

Generating dummy Data:

```
data = {'Names':['Apple','Banana','Pear', 'Watermelom'],
        'Category' :['A','B','A','B'],
        'Val1':[10,20,30,30],
        'Val2':[60,70,80,90]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

        Names Category  Val1  Val2
0       Apple        A    10    60
1      Banana        B    20    70
2        Pear        A    30    80
3  Watermelom        B    30    90
```

If we just want to OneHotEncode `Names` we would do that by

```
df_new = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Names'])
print(df_new)
```

You can refer to this [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html). By defining `columns` we would only encode columns of interest.

**Encoded Output:**

```
  Category  Val1  Val2  Names_Apple  Names_Banana  Names_Pear  Names_Watermelom
0        A    10    60            1             0           0                 0
1        B    20    70            0             1           0                 0
2        A    30    80            0             0           1                 0
3        B    30    90            0             0           0                 1
```

Comment: Hi Furqan. I cannot create the data variable manually like that as there are around 400 items under the Names column. Any suggestions on how to tackle that?

Comment: If 400 items are in a column of pandas dataframe the above code should work. Have you tried the code in solution?

Comment: My doubt is `data = {'Names':['Apple','Banana','Pear', 'Watermelon']}` contains only 4 items but it should contains 400 fruit names from the csv column.

Comment: I assume you are reading a csv which you’ve named as dataset. Replace df in 2nd last line of code with dataset. I’ve created data just to show an example.

Comment: Let me try that. Also, I originally have 3 columns in the csv but I only want to convert 1 column into an array i.e the Names column. `data= pd.read_csv('D:/fruits.csv')
data = data[:, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)`  I am getting an error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'" in this case

Comment: Use data=data.iloc[:,0] new_data=pd.get_dummies(data)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Any idea on if I want to display the corresponding column data of the next row in the initial csv in-place of the newly generated 'Index' column

Comment: Yes, if you can provide the csv or sample data then I can give you a much better solution.

Comment: Thanks mate. Let me put things in order in a new question and I will share the link with you here so that you can help me out maybe

Comment: Check the edit, I think it explains what you are trying to achieve. Please upvote if you got the desired results.