# How do I retrieve the one-hot-encoded feature names in tensorflow.keras preprocessing layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras

What is the tf.keras equivalent of encoder.get_feature_names found in sklearn? [As shown shown in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54570947/feature-names-from-onehotencoder)
Need this to get all the one-hot encoded feature names created "from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing". I will appreciate any post with example.

Comment: Can you add the name of the layer you are using? `preprocessing` is a module.

Comment: I am using preprocessing.CategoryEncoding to encode string or numeric categorical features into one-hot. I hope that helps.

Comment: CategoryEncoding doesn't even take strings as input

Comment: @NicolasGervais `preprocessing.StringLookup` to target string features and then use CategoryEncoding for the encoding. My question was, is there a way to get the feature names of all the new features created after encoding? Sklearn provides **encoder.get_feature_names**, does tf.keras has something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this. A few relevant notes:

1. I'm using the California housing dataset from scikit-learn, I haven't included that portion of the code, but train_ds is already split into X, y and the dataset is already set up.
2. I setup up this particular feature_layer using feature_columns, which I know is deprecated in favor of preprocessing layers in keras.  It was instantiated using:

```
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(                                                                                                                            
      dictionary_of_all_feature_columns.values())
```

I don't believe this should affect the use of the function below in other contexts, but I'll test it as I get to preprocessing layers in Keras. It also only handles numeric, one-hot encoded, and bucketized feature columns. I'm at the beginning of my study of feature engineering, so have not experienced too much diversity on variable types.  Will update here as I make progress over there.

```
import pandas as pd

# Get one batch of what we're going to process
[(X, y)] = train_ds.take(1)                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                            
def get_feature_names(feature_layer):
    """
    Takes as input a preprocessing layer of type 
    keras.feature_column.dense_features_v2.DenseFeatures
    and returns as output a list containing variable names in the order that 
    they are processed by the layer.  Only deals with numeric and categorical 
    variables. The one-hot encoded variable names match how scikit-learn 
    names them, namely variable_name + _ + category_in_vocabulary_list and similarly with bucket ranges.
    """                                                                                                                                        
    feature_list = []                                                                                                                                                       
    feature_layer_dictionary = feature_layer.get_config()                                                                                                                   
    list_of_encoded_features = feature_layer_dictionary["feature_columns"]                                                                                                  
    for encoded_feature in list_of_encoded_features:                                                                                                                        
        class_name = encoded_feature["class_name"]                                                                                                                          
        if class_name == 'NumericColumn':                                                                                                                                   
            feature_list.append(encoded_feature['config']['key'])                                                                                                           
        elif class_name == 'IndicatorColumn':                                                                                                                               
            variable_name = encoded_feature['config'][                                                                                                                      
                'categorical_column']['config']['key']                                                                                                                      
            category_list = list(                                                                                                                                           
                encoded_feature['config']                                                                                                                                   
                ['categorical_column']['config']                                                                                                                            
                ['vocabulary_list'])                                                                                                                                        
            for category in category_list:                                                                                                                                  
                feature_list.append(variable_name + "_" + category)                                                                                                         
        elif class_name == 'BucketizedColumn':                                                                                                                              
            variable_name = encoded_feature['config'][                                                                                                                      
                'source_column']['config']['key']                                                                                                                           
            boundary_list = list(encoded_feature['config']['boundaries'])                                                                                                   
            boundary_list.insert(0, -np.inf)                                                                                                                                
            boundary_list.append(np.inf)                                                                                                                                    
            for i in range(len(boundary_list) - 1):                                                                                                                         
                begin_bucket = str(boundary_list[i])                                                                                                                        
                end_bucket = str(boundary_list[i+1])                                                                                                                        
                both_sides_bucket = begin_bucket + "_" + end_bucket                                                                                                         
                encoded_variable_name = variable_name + "_" + both_sides_bucket                                                                                             
                feature_list.append(encoded_variable_name)                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                            
        else:                                                                                                                                                               
            pass                                                                                                                                                            
    return feature_list 
                                                                                                                                                                            
preprocessed_df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=list(X.keys()))                                                                                                                   
postprocessed_df = pd.DataFrame(                                                                                                                                            
    feature_layer(X),                                                                                                                                                       
    columns=get_feature_names(feature_layer))

[ins] In [344]: preprocessed_df.iloc[0]                                                                                                                                     
Out[344]:                                                                                                                                                                   
longitude                -119.3                                                                                                                                             
latitude                  36.34                                                                                                                                             
housing_median_age         45.0                                                                                                                                             
total_rooms              3723.0                                                                                                                                             
total_bedrooms            831.0                                                                                                                                             
population               2256.0                                                                                                                                             
households                770.0                                                                                                                                             
median_income            1.8299                                                                                                                                             
ocean_proximity       b'INLAND'                                                                                                                                             
Name: 0, dtype: object                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                            
[ins] In [345]: postprocessed_df.iloc[0]                                                                                                                                    
Out[345]:                                                                                                                                                                   
households                    0.707083                                                                                                                                      
housing_median_age_-inf_2     0.000000                                                                                                                                      
housing_median_age_2_5        0.000000                                                                                                                                      
housing_median_age_5_10       0.000000                                                                                                                                      
housing_median_age_10_15      0.000000                                                                                                                                      
housing_median_age_15_20      0.000000                                                                                                                                      
housing_median_age_20_30      0.000000                                                                                                                                      
housing_median_age_30_40      0.000000                                                                                                                                      
housing_median_age_40_inf     1.000000                                                                                                                                      
latitude                      0.334551                                                                                                                                      
longitude                     0.132462                                                                                                                                      
median_income                -1.066948                                                                                                                                      
ocean_proximity_<1H OCEAN     0.000000                                                                                                                                      
ocean_proximity_INLAND        1.000000                                                                                                                                      
ocean_proximity_NEAR OCEAN    0.000000                                                                                                                                      
ocean_proximity_NEAR BAY      0.000000                                                                                                                                      
ocean_proximity_ISLAND        0.000000                                                                                                                                      
population                    0.724704                                                                                                                                      
total_bedrooms                0.697491                                                                                                                                      
total_rooms                   0.501156                                                                                                                                      
Name: 0, dtype: float32
```